# How to know if an unexisting file can be created without trying to create it and catching an IOException

Tags: c#, file

I know this question has been asked before (actually, i found many instances of more or less the same question but with no satisfying solution yet),but i'm gonna rephrase it a little differently..
I want to use FileInfo to get an indication of whether or not i can create a (new) file on a specific disk (hard disk/usb card/etc.) and directory.

The current problems I'm facing:

1. If the file that I want to create is located on a write-protected disk/USB card/etc. - An IOException will be thrown, only the problem is that it will be thrown after a certain delay (probably after the Flush() was invoked)
2. Since the file I want to create does not exist, FileInfo.IsReadOnly will always return true, even if the given path is not actually write-protected !
   It will return false only in case where the file already exists and is not readonly.

So how can i know if it is possible to create a specific file BEFORE trying to actually create it ?

thanks..

Comment: You want to check if file exists? or do you want to check if file exists and is write-protected (meaning readOnly)?

Comment: @sachin: He wants to check wether a file can be created on the disk without creating it.. without a delay.

Answer (score 4):

This intrigued me enough to give it a go, albeit without thorough or much testing at all, here are a couple of things you might want to work with (lookout for exceptions too!):

```
    static bool CanCreateFile(FileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        if (fileInfo.Exists) return false;
        return !fileInfo.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
    }

    static bool CanCreateFile2(FileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        if (fileInfo.Exists) return false;
        return IsDirectoryWriteable(
            Path.GetDirectoryName(fileInfo.FullName));
    }

    static bool IsDirectoryWriteable(string path)
    {
        var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        if (!directoryInfo.Exists)
        {
            return IsDirectoryWriteable(directoryInfo.Parent.FullName);
        }
        return !directoryInfo.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
    }
```

But as stated in another answer, there is really no guarantee that when you actually return from 'validation' that something won't happen to change the validity of the situation before your next action of writing.

Comment: this doesn't practically work, since doing 'new DirectoryInfo("f:\\").Attributes' will yield a FileAttributes enum that only has the 'Directory' flag, and not the 'ReadOnly' flag, even if 'f:\' is a read-only flash card and you expected the ReadOnly flag to appear as well .

Answer (score 2):

In general no. Even if you could the conditions might change between you do the check and you try to create the file. E.g. the user removes a thumb drive or someone changes file permissions.

But you can build a pretty good estimate by looking at the [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) for the parent directory.
Check [`DirectoryInfo.Attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.attributes.aspx) for `FileAttributes.ReadOnly` and traverse all ACL:s in [`DirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getaccesscontrol.aspx) to find out if the current user has enough permissions.

I guess it is much easier to just try to create the file and catch the exception.

Comment: could you provide a traversal example? for me and for the other SO readers :)